# Operators are misplaced in the output of postfix notation of an infix expression given as a String

Tags: java, postfix-notation, infix-notation

Here is a Java code that takes as an input infix expression string with multiple levels of braces and mixing operands and outputs as one long postfix expression.

I converted the infix notation String to postfix because I wanted to eliminate all the braces and respect the operator precedences. Brace, Division, Multiplication, Addition, and Subtraction.

This program is not working properly. For example the output of:

> "9+3/4-(4/2)*(3+(5-2^2))"

should be

> 9 3 4 / + 4 2 / 3 5 2 2 ^ - + * -

[(according to this website)](https://www.mathblog.dk/tools/infix-postfix-converter/)

but giving me:

> 934/+42/*3522^-+-

Why this erroneous output? Is it possible to find the problem?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

class infixToPostfix{

    Stack<String> stack;
    ArrayList<String> operators;

    String postFix;

    int[] operand = {-1, -1, 1};
    int[] plusorminus = {1,2,-1};
    int[] timesordivide = {3,4,-1};
    int[] raiseto = {6,5,-1};
    int[] openparenthesis = {-1,0,-1};

    public infixToPostfix(String infix) {

        stack = new Stack<String>();
        operators = new ArrayList<String>();

        operators.add("+");
        operators.add("-");
        operators.add("x");
        operators.add("/");
        operators.add("^");
        operators.add("(");
        operators.add(")");

        postFix = new String();

        while(infix.length() > 0){

            String operand = new String();
            String operator = new String();

            if(!operators.contains(infix.substring(0, 1))){
                while(!operators.contains(infix.substring(0, 1)) && !infix.isEmpty()){
                    operand = infix.substring(0,1);
                    infix = infix.substring(1);
                }
                postFix = postFix + operand;
            }
            else if(operators.get(5).equals(infix.substring(0, 1))){
                stack.push(infix.substring(0, 1));
                infix = infix.substring(1);
            }
            else if(operators.get(6).equals(infix.substring(0, 1))){
                while(!stack.peek().equals("(")){
                    postFix = postFix + stack.pop();
                }
                stack.pop();
                infix = infix.substring(1);
            }
            else{
                operator = infix.substring(0,1);

                int[] current = getICPandISP(operator);

                if(!stack.isEmpty()){
                    int[] top = getICPandISP(stack.peek());
                    while(current[0] < top[1] && !stack.isEmpty()){
                        postFix = postFix + stack.pop();
                        if(!stack.isEmpty())
                            top = getICPandISP(stack.peek());
                    }
                }
                stack.push(operator);
                infix = infix.substring(1);
            }
        }
        postFix = postFix + infix;

        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            postFix = postFix + stack.pop();
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        return postFix;
    }

    private int[] getICPandISP(String operator){
        if(operator.equals("+") || operator.equals("-")){
            return plusorminus;
        }
        else if(operator.equals("*") || operator.equals("/")){
            return timesordivide;
        }
        else if(operator.equals("^")){
            return raiseto;
        }
        else{
            return openparenthesis;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        infixToPostfix convert = new infixToPostfix("9+3/4-(4/2)*(3+(5-2^2))");
                //"A+B/C-(A/D)*(A+(C-E^F))");
        System.out.println(convert);
    }

}
```

The output is:

> 934/+42/*3522^-+-

Comment: This is a too broad. You should  provide a [mcve] with a clear question for a specific input/output failure. Beyond that: you should consider to research the topic of *parsers*.

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution. Here it is. diff patch should be:

> - operators.add("x");
>
> + operators.add("*");

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is that there is no spacing in the output (if you have a multidigit value like "42" in your input, you won't know from the output if it was "42" or "4 2"), then insert the spaces as you build the postFix string:

Change:

```
postFix = postFix + stack.pop()
```

to:

```
postFix = postFix + " " + stack.pop()
```

(Occurs in several places - might be good to refactor into its own method.)